# Create text content based iPhone/iPad app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have basic knowledge of iPhone app development and want to create an app which would have lots of text content (kind of like tutorial). I plan to use table-view for the same (list and detail views).
Now my question is to optimize the app for both iPhone/iPad screens, how do I do that ? More text should be displayed on iPad screen Vs less text on iPhone screen..
I am not sure if that would be automatically taken care of. I am aware of 2x mode on iPad, but I do not want scaling. Any example of similar app would be really great.

Also, for the app submission, what are the current version requirements? (sdk, xcode, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have all your text content be HTML (i.e. web pages) and then each click on a section or chapter entry in your table would open up a web view that points to that HTML-formatted text page?

That would take care of your scaling and resizing issues.

Comment: Thx a lot...While that sounds to be a good idea (something i did not think of) , it would be really great if you could provide me any sample app, which does that...I have heard of web view, but never used them anywhere...also not sure how reliable they are...

Comment: Here's some [sample code from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TransWeb/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008614) (this particular one has web views but gives them a transparent background). Check it out and ElanthiraiyanS also gives a nice helpful hint.

Comment: Thx a lot...I am still unclear as to how the scaling or the page would adjust based on which screen it is viewed (iPhone/iPad)...Could you please clarify on that aspect..

Comment: Try creating a page in HTML and then displaying it in Safari on the iPad and then on the iPhone.  The behavior you see there should be roughly the same as what you'd see with a UIWebView, and I'd expect the scaling would be automatically and initially adjusted for the correct screen size.

Comment: So for my html, should i not declare any fixed px width like 200px and just give that in % like 100%?

Comment: I'd suggest to try loading those pages in Safari on iPad and on iPhone first, before building an app around that.  See how your HTML pages behave and if they look good, you should be all set!  I hope my answered helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

Michel is right. And to use a webview you could use the below code,

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[webView setDelegate:self];

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourHTMLFileName" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

To know more about UIWebView you could have a look at the documentation.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html